# How to select alphanumeric string with regex

Tags: regex

I have text like this `1960PDDO001c%20date.jpg` I only want to select this part `1960PDDO001`this part `c%20date.jpg` is not needed. I have been writing regex expression selecting only specific part on url since it is this last part is dynamic it changes from image to image i wasn't able to write a good regex. This is the full url `http://varietyvista.com/01b%20LC%20Doubled%20Dies%20Vol%202/1960%20Photos/1960PDDO001c%20date.jpg`

Comment: If you say you were writing regex expression, please add it to the question and explain what is wrong, and what you expect.

Comment: Also what are the rules for the group you're trying to extract? Is it always 11 characters? Does it always start or end with a digit? Is there always a `c%` next?

Comment: It is always 11 characters and no there is a different character everytime in place of `c%` @AndreaM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This regex will capture the eleven alphanumerical characters that follow "Photos/", regardless of what comes after them.

```
Photos\/(\w{11})
```

- `Photos` means: the literal "Photos" string.
- `\/` means: a literal `/`.
- `\w` matches any alphanumerical character or underscore (it's equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
- `{11}` specifies that the previous token needs to be present 11 times.
- `(...)` capture a group.

Comment: Thank it is working i want to ask one more thing if i also want to keep the first part of the url something like this `http://varietyvista.com/01b%20LC%20Doubled%20Dies%20Vol%202/1960%20Photos/1960PDDO001` then what should i do while maintaining your regex expression`Photos\/(\w{11})` @AndreaM

Comment: Should i use this expression `http:(.+?)Photos\/(\w{11})` @AndreaM

Comment: `.+\/(\w{11})` will do. You can use this website https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions. Please accept my answer above by clicking on the tick symbol.